# Авторизация ONVIF-устройства

Tags: java, soap, onvif

Пишу виртуальное ONVIF-устройство на базе com.sun.net.httpserver (далее - сервер). Нужно добавить возможность при создании onvif-сервера задавать произвольные имя и пароль для доступа к серверу.
Для тестирования работы сервера используется [Onvif Device Manager](https://www.polyvision.ru/po/dlya-windows/onvif-device-manager) .
Без логина-пароля сервер функционирует нормально. При задании логина-пароля в Onvif Device Manager сервер отвечает 500 по непонятной мне причине, в JaxWsLogger ошибка не перехватывается. 
Очевидно, когда задаётся логин-пароль, Onvif Device Manager присылает заголовок Security в soap-сообщении, который должен обработать мой сервер. Но мне не удаётся даже получить этот заголовок.
Что я делаю не так?

Код создания сервера. JaxWsLogger просто выводит все сообщения, которые принял или отправил сервер.

```
private HttpServer makeServer() {

        JaxWsLogger logger = new JaxWsLogger();

        HttpServer server;
        try {
            server = HttpServer.create( new InetSocketAddress( port ), 0 );
        } catch ( IOException e ) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            return null;
        }

        //Endpoint.publish("http://0.0.0.0:9999/onvif/device_service", new DeviceServiceImpl());
        Endpoint deviceService = Endpoint.create( new DeviceServiceImpl() );
        Endpoint mediaService = Endpoint.create( new MediaServiceImpl().withVideoURI( videoURI ) );
        Endpoint imagingService = Endpoint.create( new ImagingServiceImpl() );
        Endpoint deviceioService = Endpoint.create( new DeviceioServiceImpl() );
        //Endpoint discoveryLookupService = Endpoint.create( new DiscoveryLookupService() );
        //Endpoint remoteDiscoveryService = Endpoint.create( new RemoteDiscoveryService() );

        Authenticator authr = null; // useless http authentificator

        addLoggerToService( logger, deviceService );
        addLoggerToService( logger, mediaService );
        addLoggerToService( logger, imagingService );
        addLoggerToService( logger, deviceioService );
        //addLoggerToService( logger, discoveryLookupService );
        //addLoggerToService( logger, remoteDiscoveryService );

        deviceService.publish( createContext( server, "/onvif/device_service", authr ) );
        mediaService.publish( createContext( server, "/onvif/media_service", authr ) );
        imagingService.publish( createContext( server, "/onvif/imaging_service", authr ) );
        deviceioService.publish( createContext( server, "/onvif/deviceIO_service", authr ) );
        //discoveryLookupService.publish( createContext( server, "/onvif/discovery_service", authr ) );
        //remoteDiscoveryService.publish( createContext( server, "/onvif/discovery_service", authr ) );

        return server;
    }
```

Лог обмена wireshark:

запрос

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <s:Header>
        <Security s:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <UsernameToken>
                <Username>root</Username>
                <Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">802H+lCk3xd88Y/RMUhy4q4yJ7A=</Password>
                <Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">kgzQJ+t70E2q1GbijW39PioAAAAAAA==</Nonce>
                <Created xmlns="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">2018-01-15T10:53:08.000Z</Created>
            </UsernameToken>
        </Security>
    </s:Header>
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <GetCapabilities xmlns="http://www.onvif.org/ver10/device/wsdl">
            <Category>All</Category>
        </GetCapabilities>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

ответ

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
    <S:Header>
        <NotUnderstood xmlns:abc="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" qname="abc:Security" />
    </S:Header>
    <S:Body>
        <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
            <S:Code>
                <S:Value>S:MustUnderstand</S:Value>
            </S:Code>
            <S:Reason>
                <S:Text xml:lang="ru">One or more mandatory SOAP header blocks not understood</S:Text>
            </S:Reason>
        </S:Fault>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте оформить заголовок таким образом:

```
<SOAP-ENV:Header xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"> 
   <wsse:Security> 
         <wsse:UsernameToken> 
             <wsse:Username>username</wsse:Username> 
             <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">
                    tuOSpGlFlIXsozq4HFNeeGeFLEI=
              </wsse:Password> 
              <wsse:Nonce>LKqI6G/AikKCQrN0zqZFlg==</wsse:Nonce> 
              <wsu:Created>2010-09-16T07:50:45Z</wsu:Created> 
          </wsse:UsernameToken> 
    </wsse:Security> 
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```